# Access index from *ngFor outside *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have this *ngFor inside a div:

```
<div class="divRow" *ngFor="let userspec of userspecs; let i = index" id="ChosenCar">
```

Is it possible to access the  i  outside of the *ngFor? I would like to hide header columns of my table if i <= 0 but the ngFor is on the div for the data rows after the header columns.

Thanks

Comment: Why not check the length of your array outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to check `*ngIf="userspecs.length <= 0"` instead.